# client side scripting on ExpandAll and CollapseAll for DevExpress ASPxPivotGrid

Tags: devexpress

How can I use the below functions on client side scripting for DevExpress ASPxPivotGrid?

1. pivotGrid.CollapseAll()
2. pivotGrid.ExpandAll()

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Like we can expandall and collapseall rows in aspxgridview, in aspxpivotgrid these functions can be done on server side.

You can do performcallback and get the desired behavior.

I have given here sample code:

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="btnExpandAll" ClientInstanceName="btnExpandAll" runat="server">
 <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s,e){pivotGrid.Performcallback('ExpandAll')" />
 </dx:ASPxButton>
 <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnCollapseAll" ClientInstanceName="btnCollapseAll" runat="server">
  <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s,e){pivotGrid.Performcallback('CollapseAll')" />
</dx:ASPxButton>
```

Declare the pivotGrid_OnCustomCallback event and  on server side write the below code to get the functional behavior:

```
protected void pivotGrid_OnCustomCallback(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxPivotGrid.PivotGridCustomCallbackEventArgs e)
    {   
        switch (e.Parameters)
        {
            case "ExpandAll":
                pivotGrid.ExpandAll();
                break;

            case "CollapseAll":
                pivotGrid.CollapseAllRows();
                break;
        }

    }
```

You can refer to following links, May be it can help

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q264138.aspx

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q321425.aspx

http://community.devexpress.com/tags/aspxpivotgrid+expand+collapse/default.aspx